# How to combine Control and AutoAction in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

I have 2 `Manipulate` as below:-

```
m1 = Manipulate[f[t], {t, 0, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
m2 = Manipulate[f[t], Row[{Control@{t, 0, Pi}, Dynamic[Sin[t]]}]]
```

Since f is a complicated plot, I need to add `AutoAction -> False` to the `Manipulate` to ensure an smoother sliding. In `m1`, it will become `m1b = Manipulate[f[t], {t, 0, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled",AutoAction -> False}]`. But I am in fact using `m2` instead of `m1`, how can I add `AutoAction -> False` to `m2`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Control @ {t, 0, Pi}` with `Control[{t, 0, Pi, Slider, AutoAction -> False}]`:

```
m2b = Manipulate[f[t], 
  Row[{Control[{t, 0, Pi, Slider, AutoAction -> False}], Dynamic[Sin[t]]}]]
```

or

```
m2c = Manipulate[f[t], 
  Row[{Control[{t, 0, Pi, Slider[##, AutoAction -> False]&}], Dynamic[Sin[t]]}]]
```

Comment: Many thanks for reply. But there's a problem inside. `Manipulate[t, 
 Row[{Control[{{t, 0, 1}, Slider, AutoAction -> False}], Dynamic[t]}]]` works, but `Manipulate[t, 
 Row[{Control[{{t, 2, 3}, Slider, AutoAction -> False}], Dynamic[t]}]]` doesn't work...